# Specifying range in regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, sed, vi

I am trying to use regular expressions to find a string within a longer string (see attached example).  I am working in Vi at the moment.  The regular expression I am using is **[CT]A...T** (bold denotes the string used).  I would like to only find examples that are a fixed range from the [ character.  I have tried using **[CT]A...T.{5,10}[** but this did not work, nor did **[CT]A...T.{5,10}[**.  I also tried 
**[CT]A...T.[.....-......-.......-........-.........][**  with no success as the [.*] is not okay in regex I guess.  I'm out of ideas at the moment and cannot find anything else on the internet.

EDIT
What I would like is to find only the regular expression [CT]A...T string 5-10 characters upstream of the [ character.  so CATAATAATTCC[  or TATAATCGACAGAA[.  I've placed ** around some examples below of what it would find.

Example set:

```
AACGGTTGGAGCAGCGTTCACCTGACGC**TATACTGCTTCT[**C]TTTCTTATTGCTCAAACTG
TTCCTGGTTATTTTGCCGCAGGTCAGCG**TATCGTGAACAT[**C]TTTTCCAGTGTTCAGTAGG
AGATAATGCGAAAAAACAGCCTTTCCGG**TACTCTACGGCG[**G]TTTTATCGTCCTGTAGAGA
TGAAACCGTTGTTTATTCATGCGTTGCGATTAACAATACG[C]TTTTCCAGAGAGCGGCTTT
TCGCTTCAATTTCGACCAGCCATCCTCTATTCTGATGGGT[A]TTTACCACTGGTCCCGGAA
AATGGCGAGTAATTGCCAGTTGATCCTGGTATCATCAGAG[C]TTTGCTGCATCTGCTGAAG
AGAAGTGGAATCCCGACTGCATATCGCGTAGTGTAGAACG[G]CCTTTTTTTCGTCAACCGT
TTTCCACACCTAAAATGCTATTTCTGCGATAATAGCAACC[G]TTTCGTGACAGGAATCACG
CCTAGTTTGCTTACGGACTCACAGGGCGTAAACTAGCGCC[G]TTTTTTTAAGTGATGAGAA
TGGCTGTATTTGCCGCACCGCGCAGGTATACTCCTTTCCT[G]GTTTTTTTAATCACTACGT
GAGAATTGACTCCGGAGTGTACAATTATTACAATCCGGCC[T]CTTTAATCACCCATGGCTT
GGCAGTTGGTTGACGGTGAAACGCGTATTAAAATGCCACC[C]TTTACACCCTGGTGGTGAC
TTTTCATCGCTCAAGGCGGGCCGTGTAACGTATAATGCGG[C]TTTGTTTAATCATCATCTA
ACACGATGTCACGGTAACGCCTGTACGGTAAACTATGCGG[G]TTTACGGTCAGTACCCACA
AATCCTTCCTTTCCCCGGCAGCTGGCGTTATGGTCAGATG[G]TTTTTGCAACAAATCTCAC
ACTGTATATTCATTCAGGTCAATTTGTGTCATAATTAACC[G]TTTGTGATCGCCGGTAGCA
CAACATAGTAAAAGCGCTATTGGTAATGGTACAATCGCGC[G]TTTACACTTATTCAGAACG
TTCGGTTGAAAAAGCCGCTATGATCGCCGGATAATCGTTT[G]CTTTTTTTACCACCCGTTT
TATCGTCGGCGTACCAGACGGTGTGTGGTATACTTACGGG[G]TTTTTCTTCATTGTATGGT
CCGCCTTTATTATATTCATACGGGATATTGCTATTGTTTC[T]TTTTCCCTGGGATTTGTCA
AATGCTTGCGCCGCTTCTGACGATGAGTATAATGCCGGAC[A]ATTTGCCGGGAGGATGTAT
GAGTAGCCAGAGTAGCGGCATTGTTGCGGATAATGGTCAG[G]TTTACCTCAGCGGAATGCC
AGTGACTATATTGATCCACAATTGCGTGTATCATAGATGT[T]TTGCCCATCAGGGGCGACC
```

Comment: You haven't really been clear what exactly you're trying to match.

Comment: What exactly `[CT]A...T./{5,10/}[` is supposed to do?

Comment: sorry, as the edit states, I only want to find the string [CT]A...T when it is 5-10 characters upstream of the [ character in the text.

Comment: I'm kind of confused.  When you write that you're looking for a string that starts with `[CT]`, are you referring to the literal square bracket characters, or the regex special characters?  Are you saying you want your string to start with either `[C]` or `[T]`?

Comment: Could you please tell us the string you are trying to match or perhaps highlight it in the blob above. Would make things easier for us :-)

Comment: [CT]A...T is the REGEX i'd like to find.  I'd like to find this regex only if it is within 5-10 characters of the "[" character in the string I am searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe following regex should work for you:

```
[CT].{5,10}\[
```

Using egrep:

```
egrep -o '[CT].{5,10}\[' file
TACTGCTTCT[
TCGTGAACAT[
CTCTACGGCG[
TTAACAATACG[
TTCTGATGGGT[
TATCATCAGAG[
TGTAGAACG[
TAATAGCAACC[
CTAGCGCC[
CTCCTTTCCT[
CAATCCGGCC[
TGCCACC[
TATAATGCGG[
CTATGCGG[
TGGTCAGATG[
CATAATTAACC[
TACAATCGCGC[
TAATCGTTT[
TACTTACGGG[
CTATTGTTTC[
TAATGCCGGAC[
TAATGGTCAG[
TCATAGATGT[
```

Comment: Ah that works, I did not know i needed the apostrophes.  I suppose it won't work in vim since it has only basic REGEX...  Any way I could use this to highlight it in the text?

Comment: I suppose I can do this by replacing the -o option with the color option.